# IndexError: tuple index out of range for y_train in CNN

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, conv-neural-network

I'm currently attempting to compare the performance on my dataset between different types of NN and thus, first I am attempting to use a Convolutional Neural Network (CNN).

Unfortunately, I am getting the error `IndexError: tuple index out of range` for the line `model.add(Dense(y_train.shape[1], activation='softmax'))` in the code below.

The input shapes for X_train and y_train are as follows:

```
X_train : (89680, 25)
y_train : (89680,)
```

The output of `dataset.head()` is as follows:

```
FrameLen_0  FrameLen_1  FrameCapLen_0  FrameCapLen_1  ...  TLSRecordContentType_0  TLSRecordLen_0  TLSAppData_0  PacketTime_0
0         116        66.0            116           66.0  ...                    23.0            45.0            45      0.000028    
1         116        66.0            116           66.0  ...                    23.0            45.0            45      0.000026    
2         116        66.0            116           66.0  ...                    23.0            45.0            45      0.000024    
3         116        66.0            116           66.0  ...                    23.0            45.0            45      0.000025    
4         116        66.0            116           66.0  ...                    23.0            45.0            45      0.000028    

[5 rows x 25 columns]
```

I cannot figure out why I am getting this error. Here is the code:

```
import os
import ast
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import tensorflow as tf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import itertools
import keras.backend as K
import scipy
import scipy.sparse as sp
import seaborn as sn
import random
from string import ascii_uppercase
from keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, LSTM, Dropout, Activation, Flatten
from keras.layers import Convolution2D, Conv1D, Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, LeakyReLU, ELU, MaxPooling1D
from keras.utils import np_utils, to_categorical, plot_model
from keras import metrics
from keras.optimizers import SGD, Adam, Adadelta
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.feature_selection import SelectKBest, f_classif
from sklearn.utils import class_weight
from skmultilearn.model_selection import iterative_train_test_split
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler, MinMaxScaler, RobustScaler, OneHotEncoder, LabelEncoder, Normalizer
from itertools import tee  # finally! I found something useful for it
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix, classification_report, accuracy_score
import matplotlib.font_manager as fm
from matplotlib.collections import QuadMesh

SEED = 12345
random.seed(SEED) # for reproducibility

def bytes_to_len_bytes(s):
    try:
        s = s.replace(':', ' ')
        l = len(bytes.fromhex(s))
    except:
        l = 0
    return l

def get_class_counts(df, target):
    grp = df.groupby(target).nunique()
    return {key: grp[key] for key in list(grp.keys())}

def get_class_proportions(df, target):
    class_counts = get_class_counts(df, target)
    return {val[0]: round(val[1] / df.shape[0], 4) for val in class_counts.items()}


######


# Pre-preprocessing
dataset = pd.read_csv('dataset.csv')

target = dataset.pop('Movement')
others = dataset[['Distance', 'Speed', 'Delay', 'Loss']]

dataset.drop(['Distance', 'Speed', 'Delay', 'Loss'], axis=1, inplace=True) # Drop other classes for now..

dataset['Payload_0'] = dataset['Payload_0'].apply(lambda x: bytes_to_len_bytes(x)) #.astype(str)
dataset['TLSAppData_0'] = dataset['TLSAppData_0'].apply(lambda x: bytes_to_len_bytes(x)) #.astype(str)

print(dataset.head())



# Use 20% of samples for testing (test_size=0.2)
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(dataset, target, shuffle=True, random_state=SEED, stratify=target, test_size=0.2)

# Check the proportions are even from stratification
# print("train data proportions", get_class_proportions(X_train, target))
# print("test data proportions", get_class_proportions(X_test, target))

# Normalise the training set and testing set individually
# to ensure truly *unseen* nature of test dataset
sc = RobustScaler().fit(X_train) # MinMaxScaler() # We use robust scaler to reduce influence of possible outliers
X_train_normalised = sc.transform(X_train)
X_test_normalised = sc.transform(X_test)

# Use 20% of samples for validation (0.25 * 0.8 = 0.2) so we end up with 60-20-20 for train/test/validation
X_train, X_val, y_train, y_val = train_test_split(X_train, y_train, test_size=0.25, random_state=SEED)

######

print(X_train.shape)
print(y_train.shape)


# Construct CNN

# init model
model = Sequential()
# add layers
model.add(Conv1D(filters=64, kernel_size=1, activation='relu', input_shape=X_train.shape))
model.add(Conv1D(filters=64, kernel_size=1, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=2))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(100, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(y_train.shape[1], activation='softmax'))
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy']) # 'rmsprop'

history = model.fit(X_train, y_train, validation_data=(X_val, y_val), epochs=250, verbose=1)
# print(history)

plt.figure(figsize=(8,10))
plt.subplot(2,1,1)

# summarize history for accuracy
plt.plot(history.history['accuracy'])
plt.plot(history.history['val_accuracy'])
plt.title('model accuracy')
plt.ylabel('accuracy')
plt.xlabel('epoch')
plt.legend(['train', 'validation'], loc='lower right')

plt.subplot(2,1,2)
# summarize history for loss
plt.plot(history.history['loss'])
plt.plot(history.history['val_loss'])
plt.title('model loss')
plt.ylabel('loss')
plt.xlabel('epoch')
plt.legend(['train', 'validation'], loc='upper right')
plt.show()

scores = model.evaluate(X_test, y_test)
print(scores)

y_pred = model.predict(X_test)
print(y_pred)
y_pred = np.argmax(y_pred, axis=1)
y_test = np.argmax(y_test, axis=1)

accuracy_score = accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred)
print("Accuracy Score: ", accuracy_score)
confusion_matrix = confusion_matrix(y_test, y_pred)
print(confusion_matrix)
class_report = classification_report(y_test, y_pred, target_names=target_names)
print(class_report)


##
```

Comment: The error is quite clear `y_train` has a single dimension `(89680,)`. There is only one item in the tuple at index `0`, but then you try adding `y_train.shape[1]` to your model, which of course will rise `index error`.

Comment: Yes I knew that is true, however the solution is unclear.

Comment: Try `model.add(Dense(89680, activation='softmax'))`

Comment: @alec_djinn that gives `ValueError: Input 0 of layer sequential is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=3, found ndim=2. Full shape received: [None, 25]`

Comment: How many classes are there in your data set? If there are more than 2 classes, then just need to update model.add(Dense(y_train.shape[1], activation='softmax')). If there are only two classes, then you need to change `loss` to `binary_crossentropy` and `softmax` to `sigmoid`. Thanks